# Using pydbgr with Emacs

Tags: python, debugging, emacs, elisp, dot-emacs

Has anyone used **Pydbgr** with Emacs and if so would they mind sharing their **.emacs** configuration plus any associated elisp sources required.

The installation instructions can be found at:

http://code.google.com/p/pydbgr/wiki/Tutorial#Installation

**Pydbgr** looks like a really useful extension to the capabilities of **pdb**, especially its support for multi-threaded debug and the promise of conducting this within Emacs, but I cannot find any elisp source allowing for easy integration in the Emacs environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see http://github.com/rocky/emacs-dbgr which supports a number of debuggers, pydbgr being one of them.

Comment: I set the variable pydbgr-command-name to be the full path to pdbgr in my currently active virtualenv, but M-x pdbgr is not picking this up. Can you clarify how I can reference a specific pdbgr command and thereby get this working with virtualenv installation like mine. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Was a bug in the code which is now fixed on github.com with SHA1 short hash 1a188fd